# MySQL: Most efficient column type for type (not mime but system or user generated)

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to think of the most efficient TYPE for MySQL to store what amounts to SYSTEM or USER generated (for the row). SYSTEM generated items can't be deleted, USER generated items can be. I'm thinking **INT** with a 1/2 for possible values (1:USER || 2:SYSTEM) though I would like input from others. This has nothing to do with mime/media type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided that I will use the user's id for this column.

To edit/delete/etc the person doing so must either be...

1.) The person who created it.

2.) A person with a higher level of permissions.

I'm trying to keep everything as generic as possible to get as unique perspectives as possible and this approach seems like it will endure the longest possible array of changes in the future.

Answer (score 1):

`ENUM` type can be helpful for preventing bad inputs.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/enum.html

Comment: Is this SQL neutral (e.g. PostgreSQL, MySQL, MSSQL)?

Comment: Not in SQL Server, but I suggested it because you mentioned `MySQL` explictly. :)

Comment: Looks good, how do I set it up in phpMyAdmin please? I don't yet see how to set the static values that will be represented in the table row.

Comment: Looks like enum is expensive should I choose to add different options: http://komlenic.com/244/8-reasons-why-mysqls-enum-data-type-is-evil/ I think I will stick with INT however I DID learn something from your post so up voting, thanks.

Comment: @John Hmm, I still think ENUM fits for this situation, but I agree with many part of the linked document. Nice doc. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Instead of going with a 1/2 value I'm going to use the user's id instead and base it off of their permissions. See my self-answer below for clarification if interested.

Comment: ENUM is actually very cheap, because only the indexes are stored as data. Be careful with updating the column definition though.